# Navigation issue with keyboard up and down key in ui-grid table

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

when using up/down arrow and enter to navigate, sometimes cursor skips a cell when hitting the arrow key just once. And it becomes non-editing when the cell navigates to out of the visible area.

it becomes non editable in up and down of last displayed row (Like 10 rows displays at a time so after 10 rows when we down keypress then it becomes non editable and sometimes it skips row.)

so any idea about how always it will be editable and not skipping the row.

`<!--  http://plnkr.co/edit/WizlYTzwdif3Exp1pTDT?p=preview   -->`